# video gallery with youtube videos - cannot embed

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

I try to  implement a video gallery with youtube videos.

This is the code for now.

```
//html...
<div id="videogal" ></div>


//javascript
//initializing the gallery
//mplv is an array, getting data after a query in the db
//mplv[0] contains https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hLgJjlFIxGA
document.getElementById("videogal").innerHTML='<object id="viewer" width="575" height="344"><embed  src="' + mplv[0] + '" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" width="575" height="344"></embed></object>';
```

I cannot get it to work. In FF and IE and GC all I get is a blank `div` where the youtube video should be.

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance

EDIT

More info and code, as Adam asked

User clicks on a point in an custom-made openlayers map.

```
//this activated when a point is clicked
function selected_feature(event){
   //openlayers stuff here....
   //query , and fill mplv[]
   //simply call
    videogaledit(0);

   //0 is for initialize, like setting the first video 
}
```

and then

```
function videogaledit(j) {

if (j==0){

    alert('what is the link now    '+mplv[0]);//works fine


    document.getElementById("videogal").innerHTML='<object id="viewer" width="575" height="344"><embed  src="' + mplv[0] + '" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" width="575" height="344"></embed></object>';

}
```

`selected_feature(event)` is  inside `init(){` which is called from `<body onload='init();'>`
`videogaledit` is outside `init`

Comment: Need more code. Is the javascript statement in your question executed after the DOM has finished loading?

Comment: @Adam I just added more info and code. Thanks

Comment: @Adam Just an idea...How can I check what mplv[0] contains? Except using `alert`? Maybe link has some extra "?

Comment: @Adam Thanks for your time. I found a solution. Check it, if you like

Answer (score 0):

Reference: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Demo here: http://mattia-asti.it/tests/youtube.html

(Hosted on my website because jsfiddle dont work with iframe I suppose)

```
<!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
<div id="player"></div>

<script>

var mplv = ['hLgJjlFIxGA'];

var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '344',
        width: '575',
        videoId: mplv[0]
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: That sounds good.  But, unfortunately, here is why cannot work in my case. Back-end users insert youtube links to the db. Those back-end users just paste a link like so `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hLgJjlFIxGA` in a text field and this is inserted in the db. This is what `mplv[]` contains. So this is the only thing I can use...I try to use  something more simple like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_youtube.asp), the second example. But, dynamically change it with javascript.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I found a solution. Check it if you like.

Comment: You can easly trim the url with a function like substring.
`var mplv = ['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hLgJjlFIxGA'];`
    `mplv[0] = mplv[0].substring(32,mplv[0].length);`

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the solution... This is just a draft. Works fine, but I should say, I get some warnings in the console, mostly about CSS.

So here is the code.

```
//html
<div id="videogal" ></div>


//javascript

//at the begining of javascript, outside init function
var elemv = document.createElement("video");
elemv.setAttribute("height", "600");
elemv.setAttribute("width", "800");
elemv.setAttribute("controls", "true");
elemv.setAttribute("type","application/x-shockwave-flash");

//function selected_feature(event) stays the same

//initializing...
function videogaledit(j) {

if (j==0){
     if(mtyv[0]=='v')
     {document.getElementById("videogal").innerHTML=' ';
      elemv.src=mplv[0];
      document.getElementById("videogal").appendChild(elemv);   
     }

//
     if(mtyv[0]=='y'){
     document.getElementById("videogal").innerHTML='<object id="viewer" >'+mplv[0]+'</object>';
     }
```

`mplv[0]` now contains `<iframe width="640" height="360" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/1RXiNkrqxbs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

I guess I can tell my users to copy that code instead of the link.

`mtyv[0]` its another array that got data from the db , after the query. Contains `y` for youtube data or `v` for videos like `upolad/aVideoUploadedByAUser.mp4`

Works for both youtube and videos uploaded on server. Also works on GC 29.0, FF 24 and IE 10.

The most frightening error I get is in the Chrome's console. Says  `Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.youtube.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://localhost". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.  www-embed-player-vfln1DfCN.js:101`

Honestly, I have no idea what it actually means and how to debug this.